# ドメイン駆動のエンティティ(Entity)とテーブルの関係について

Tags: ドメイン駆動設計, アーキテクチャ

ドメイン駆動のエンティティは、必ずしもテーブルに一致しないケースがあると認識しています。

それを前提に、例えば「1つのエンティティにて複数のテーブルに存在するデータを保持」しても問題ないでしょうか？

またリポジトリで処理されるデータが複数テーブルにまたがって問題ないか？についても質問したいです。

**前提条件**

- エンティティに沿ってテーブル構造が変更できない(しにくい)
- (インフラ層都合でエンティティの定義を自由にできない)

**簡易的なテーブル構造の例**

```
ユーザー設定テーブル1: 対象1, 対象2
ユーザー設定テーブル2: 対象3, 対象4
ユーザー設定テーブル3: 対象5, 対象6
```

Answer (score 2):

クリーンアーキテクチャやヘキサゴナルアーキテクチャのような、ドメインモデルが外部の技術要素に依存しない設計方針を選んだ場合（大抵はそうだと思いますが）、ドメインモデルは自身がどのような形で永続化されるか、関知しません。
従って、１つのエンティティを同じ構造のテーブルに入れようが、複数テーブルに分けようが、構わないわけです。
むしろ、**ドメインモデルからの依存が無いからこそ**、性能などを考慮した自由なテーブル設計が可能と言えます。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。テーブル構造を無視すれば、スムーズにエンティティ構造を考えられますが、データ構造の都合を考慮すると、エンティティの定義に苦慮する時があります。極端に問題を単純にすると下記のような話です。

「エンティティ → 複数テーブルに保管(データ更新)」

この場合の具体的な解決例などありますでしょうか？(Serviceで処理するべきか?、Repositoryで処理するべきか?など気になります)

Comment: なにか私と認識がずれていそうです。なぜ、ドメインモデルのエンティティを定義するにあたって、データ構造の都合を考慮する必要があるのでしょうか？　順序が逆のはずです。

Comment: 上記は私も認識してはいますが、既にテーブルが存在し、またテーブルも変更できない状況という制約を付け加えさせてください(※仕様・工数など、現実面から発生する不可避の制約です)

Comment: 仮に既にテーブル定義が存在するとしても、まだよく分かりません。１つのエンティティが複数テーブルに分かれているだけですよね？　リポジトリの実装内部でその変換をすれば良いだけ、というわけにはいきませんか？

Comment: 実際、１つのエンティティが複数テーブルに分かれるのは、よくあることです。子エンティティを持っていたり、値オブジェクトのリストを持っていたり、といったドメイン構造は十分ありえますので。

Comment: もしかして、O/Rマッパー等を使っていることによる制約が生じているために困っていますか？　例えば、O/Rマッパーを使って、テーブルとドメインのエンティティを直接マッピングさせているだとか。